# Grab a product description from a tab

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I would like to take the product description from ONE tab only, unfortunately all tabs are loaded into the .csv file.

Code is:

```
# scrapy Spider Definition
import scrapy
import csv


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"

    # URLs, die das Spider durchsuchen soll
    start_urls = [
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/microsoft-office-2021-home-and-student/'
    ]

    # Parser-Funktion für die Start-URL
    def parse(self, response):
        # Produktname auswählen
        product_title = response.css(
            'h1[class="product--title"]::text').get()
        if product_title:
            product_title = product_title.strip()

        # Produktpreis auswählen
        product_price = response.css(
            'meta[itemprop="price"]::attr(content)').get()

        # Produktbeschreibung auswählen
        product_description = response.css(
            'div.product--description').xpath('.//text()').getall()
        if product_description:
            product_description = " ".join(product_description).strip()

        # CSV-Datei erstellen und Produktname und Preis hinzufügen
        filename = 'product.csv'
        with open(filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(
                ['Product Title', 'Product Price', 'Product Description'])
            writer.writerow(
                [product_title, product_price, product_description])

        # Bestätigungsnachricht anzeigen
        self.log(
            f'Produktname "{product_title}", Preis "{product_price}" und Beschreibung "{product_description}" wurden erfolgreich in {filename} gespeichert.')
```

Who can help here, only the Description tab should be clawed.

Answer (score 1):

When you're getting the "description" it's actually three different `div` tags. You need a more specific selector to get only the text from first `div` tag.

Besides that there's no need to write to the CSV file yourself, you can just use Scrapy's [FEEDS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=feeds#feeds) and let it do it for you.

```py
# scrapy Spider Definition
import scrapy


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"

    # URLs, die das Spider durchsuchen soll
    start_urls = [
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/microsoft-office-2021-home-and-student/'
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': {
            'product.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'fields': ['Product Title', 'Product Price', 'Product Description'],
            }
        }
    }

    # Parser-Funktion für die Start-URL
    def parse(self, response):
        # Produktname auswählen
        # you can lose the "if" statement by setting the default value to an rmpty string and then strip it
        product_title = response.css('h1[class="product--title"]::text').get(default='').strip()

        # Produktpreis auswählen
        product_price = response.css('meta[itemprop="price"]::attr(content)').get()

        # Produktbeschreibung auswählen
        product_description = response.xpath('//div[@itemprop="description"]//text()').getall()
        if product_description:
            product_description = " ".join(product_description).strip()

        # CSV-Datei erstellen und Produktname und Preis hinzufügen
        filename = 'product.csv'
        yield {
            'Product Title': product_title,
            'Product Price': product_price,
            'Product Description': product_description
        }

        # Bestätigungsnachricht anzeigen
        self.log(f'Produktname "{product_title}", \
                    Preis "{product_price}" und Beschreibung "{product_description}" \
                     wurden erfolgreich in {filename} gespeichert.')
```